# How can I use '&' VB operator in a SQL query in ASP.NET / C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How can I use '&' VB operator in C# Asp.net SQL query from the following code. The below code is of VB.

```
query = "select top 1 * from Name Where ID=" & Order(0)
```

My code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top(1) * from Name where ID=", & order[0], con)
```

Which throws me a syntax error. I tried using '+' in between `where ID=", + order[0], con)` but it wasn't able to get the value stored in order[0]. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: `&` is not Bitwise it is concatenation in VB

Comment: Oh sorry! wrongly framed. Yes concatenation is what i meant.

Comment: what is the data type of order[]?

Comment: @KyleBurns : Integer

Comment: If you don't mean Bitwise then clean up the question

Comment: In c# strings can be concatenated using the + operator `string gm = "good " + "morning";` Since `order[0]` return an int you have to convert it to a string first `order[0].ToString()`

Answer (score 10):

That C# equivalent to VB's `&` string concatenation operator will look like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 1 * from Name where ID=" + order[0].ToString(), con)
```

### BUT DON'T DO THAT!

That technique is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. For this and other reasons you should build the query like this instead:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 1 * from Name where ID= @ID", con)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = order[0];
```

Comment: There's no need to `ToString` `order[0]`.  The `+` operator has a `(string, object)` overload.

Comment: @Evk injection is the most important reason to use query parameters, but it's not the only reason. I'll clarify my answer slightly.

Comment: Oh, and `int` does not guarantee injection safety in all situations. You can override the default system number formats on windows systems  to include arbitrary text, and sometimes use that feature to craft injection on int query values. Probably not here, but the idea that int = safe is not bullet-proof.

Comment: Override default number formats, so nothing is safe? Hopefully you would need a login to the server to make that sort of change.

Comment: @buffjape Think old-school client server program running winforms, where the SQL string is generated on the client. If users have admin rights on their local workstations (and many environments still allow this), you've lost. Random peon end-user just hacked your sql server. Go parameters or go home.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn This is an ASP application.

Comment: @Servy that's why the "probably not here" line a few comments earlier. It's just the general idea the int = safe doesn't always hold, and even if it did it's still poor practice for other reasons.

Comment: Thank you @JoelCoehoorn you explained the problem very well.

Answer (score -1):

string interpolation is a much more readable way to go here.  While I wouldn't necessarily build a dynamic SQL string at all out of concern for exposing to SQL injection attacks, the way to build a string like what you're looking for in a more readable manner would be to do something like:

`var statement = $"select top(1) * from Name where Id={orders[0]}";`

Comment: As stated by another answer, this is vulnerable to injection attacks. While technically answering the question, I don't think it is a good practice to use code like that, and especially bad to recommend this code to new users / learners. the good practice is to use a SqlCommand parameter

Comment: @Pac0 If orders is an integer array there can be no injection attack

Comment: @Paparazzi That's not entirely true. You can override the default number format on Windows systems to include arbitrary text, and sometime you can leverage that to accomplish injection on an int value. While it likely doesn't apply here, the idea that int = safe is not 100% bulletproof. As always, go parameters or go home.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn An end user cannot do that

Comment: @Paparazzi Sometimes they can. Again, likely here they cannot. But I've seen environments where end users have admin rights on their own workstations while using winforms client apps that build sql strings on the local system for execution on the company's Sql Server. In that scenario, and end user absolutely can accomplish injection.

Comment: @Paparazzi : Also, don't forget that code can evolve, and sometimes developers fail to see every implication. For example : "*numeric ids are bad for some reasons, let's change this field to a GUID string*" . I admit it's not likely, but it happens more often than it should, and this kind of overlooking causes exploits on the long term.

Comment: @Pac0 Yes lots of stuff can happen

Comment: @Paparazzi not sure if your last comment was being sarcastic ;) , but yes, exactly, lots of stuff happens, and one of the main goals of good practices is to help you avoid lots of (sometimes dramatic) problems that could happen just by following them.

Comment: @Pac0 I am not putting change that to GUID and taking GUID as user input high on the list of things that could happen.

Comment: @Paparazzi I admit this example is a poor one. Just that one cannot always think about everything. And good practices help to eliminate a lot of cases, while having nearly no downside.  I have another example, that I have seen a lot these last months : "*Hey Mr. Junior developer, please write a C# function to search for names in db. If you don't know how to do that, just look elsewhere in the code, there are similar things done. Now I got to go.*", and now Mr. Junior developer copied the function replacing order[0] by another parameter, which is a string.

Answer (score -1):

you just need `@` before starting query:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select top(1) * from Name where ID='"+ order[0] +"'", con);
```